# non linear scaling of y-axis around zero

Tags: pgfplots

I would to plot a data series with a focus on the behavior at zero crossing. Logarithmic x-y-scaling cannot be applied because of there are negative y-values. I tried scaling to scale the y-axis with a hyperbolic sine through a coordinate. Somehow, the sample code does not plot data with negative values, although the inverse hyperbolic sine should also defined for negative real numbers.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
        x, y
        0.000, -11.593
        1000.000, 394200.483
        0.029, -11.595
        500.015, 191387.137
        0.060, -11.598
        250.037, 89886.332
        0.092, -11.601
        125.065, 38883.652
        0.129, -11.604
        62.597, 12269.691
        0.188, -11.610
        31.393, 731.387
        0.676, -11.679
        16.034, -15.857
        23.713, -17.985
        27.553, -19.100
        29.473, 292.001
        27.671, -19.121
        28.572, 88.339 
        27.831, -19.150
        28.201, 5.087  
        28.124, -12.353
        28.178, -0.001
        28.179, 0.111
    \end{filecontents*}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{ln(#1 + sqrt( #1^2 + 1))}\pgfmathresult},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult},
     }
    \begin{axis}[
    %   xmode=log,
        grid=major,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1000,
        ymin=0]
        \addplot+[only marks] table[col sep=comma,x=x,y=y] {\jobname.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Side question: How can I make to y-labels be the actual function values and their scaled ones? My idea is to use something like `yticks={ln(1), ln(10+sqrt(10^2+1), ...}` and `yticklabels={1,10,...}'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `y coord inv trafo` is not applied to coordinates, but to tick positions. So in order to get a different scaling for negative coordinates you can use pgfmaths `ifthenelse`. Additionally in some places `#1` must be put in `()`, if negative tick coordinates are given manually with `ytick`.

For the `ytick`s itself, if you want to use some math expression you have to put them in `()` too. But you don't realy need this here, because the given coordinates are also transformed with `y coord trafo`.

Caution, there will be `dimension too large` errors for values greater than 127 with your equations, because 128^2 will exceed the maximum of 16383.99999.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
    x, y
    0.000, -11.593
    1000.000, 394200.483
    0.029, -11.595
    500.015, 191387.137
    0.060, -11.598
    250.037, 89886.332
    0.092, -11.601
    125.065, 38883.652
    0.129, -11.604
    62.597, 12269.691
    0.188, -11.610
    31.393, 731.387
    0.676, -11.679
    16.034, -15.857
    23.713, -17.985
    27.553, -19.100
    29.473, 292.001
    27.671, -19.121
    28.572, 88.339 
    27.831, -19.150
    28.201, 5.087  
    28.124, -12.353
    28.178, -0.001
    28.179, 0.111
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,#1,ln((#1) + sqrt((#1)^2 + 1)))}},
 }
\begin{axis}[
%   xmode=log,
    grid=major,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1000,
% remove to get negative y coordinates
%    ymin=0,
% works with '()' around coordinates
%    ytick={(ln(1)),(ln(10+sqrt(10^2+1)))},
%    yticklabels={1,10},
% needs '()' around '#1' in y coord trafo for negative numbers
    ytick={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    yticklabels={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] table[col sep=comma,x=x,y=y] {\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]