# PGFPlots: Trying to create a non-linear axis using trafo/.code in \newcommand - how to escape the #1 argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I would like to make my Y axis non-linear. I have found an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396471/non-linear-scaling-of-y-axis-around-zero) but the problem is that my code for charts is encapsulated in the `\newcommand` environment. When I use something like this:

```
\pgfplotsset{
        y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{ln(#1 + sqrt( #1^2 + 1))}\pgfmathresult},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult},
     }
```

The `#1` argument is replaced by the command argument value. Is there a way to escape it or something to make this work?

MWE - taken and edited from the linked thread (works when the `\newcommand` is removed):

```
\newcommand{\makeChart}[1]{
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
    x, y
    0.000, -11.593
    1000.000, 394200.483
    0.029, -11.595
    500.015, 191387.137
    0.060, -11.598
    250.037, 89886.332
    0.092, -11.601
    125.065, 38883.652
    0.129, -11.604
    62.597, 12269.691
    0.188, -11.610
    31.393, 731.387
    0.676, -11.679
    16.034, -15.857
    23.713, -17.985
    27.553, -19.100
    29.473, 292.001
    27.671, -19.121
    28.572, 88.339 
    27.831, -19.150
    28.201, 5.087  
    28.124, -12.353
    28.178, -0.001
    28.179, 0.111
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,#1,ln((#1) + sqrt((#1)^2 + 1)))}},
 }
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1000,
    ytick={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    yticklabels={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] table[col sep=comma,x=x,y=y] {\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeChart{something}
```

Comment: A MWE would be nice.  Maybe you could save the content of `#1` into a variable and use that instead?

Comment: @Jan MWE is just whatever chart encapsulated in a `\newcommand`. Not sure about the variable. The `#1` gets replaced in the whole command. I understand that in the `trafo` the `#1` needs to be used as the argument of their own macro so there is a conflict. Like injecting our own code there right? Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: @Jan Added the MWE after all....

Comment: Can you have `filecontents` in the argument of a command? And what would be the reason for such complicated approach?

Comment: @egreg Well I use the same chart type for many datasets and edit just some labels etc. so I have one command to create the chart that I use with different arguments. Not sure what you mean with the filecontents, the problem is that the #1 gets overwritten in the trafo code.

Comment: Why do you put all the preamble in the newcommand? Even the documentclass? This is not supported at all, I think.

Comment: @Rmano Sorry, that was a mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You ***cannot*** have `filecontents*` in the argument of another command; this would result in an empty file being written out.
2. After you move `filecontents*` outside of the definition, simply change `#1` into `##1` in the code for `trafo`, so this would refer to the value given to the key.

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.dat}
    x, y
    0.000, -11.593
    1000.000, 394200.483
    0.029, -11.595
    500.015, 191387.137
    0.060, -11.598
    250.037, 89886.332
    0.092, -11.601
    125.065, 38883.652
    0.129, -11.604
    62.597, 12269.691
    0.188, -11.610
    31.393, 731.387
    0.676, -11.679
    16.034, -15.857
    23.713, -17.985
    27.553, -19.100
    29.473, 292.001
    27.671, -19.121
    28.572, 88.339 
    27.831, -19.150
    28.201, 5.087  
    28.124, -12.353
    28.178, -0.001
    28.179, 0.111
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\makeChart}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(##1<0,##1,ln((##1) + sqrt((##1)^2 + 1)))}},
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1000,
    ytick={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    yticklabels={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] table[col sep=comma,x=x,y=y] {\jobname.dat};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\makeChart{something}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you define a macro, the idea is (I think) to reuse that. So, you should never load packages etc. in a macro --- and most of the settings could be done outside. Moreover, your macro does not use the argument at all.

I interpreted your question like the following. I suppose you want to keep the `y coord trafo` *inside* the macro (although, unless it is different for each graph, is not needed at all) and I took the freedom to use the argument as the data file name.  To have a literal  `#1` in the body of a macro, simply double the `#`: `##1`.

You also ignored a couple of warnings that I take care of --- `filecontents` is in the kernel now, and `compat=` is needed for `pgfplots`.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{something.dat}
    x, y
    0.000, -11.593
    1000.000, 394200.483
    0.029, -11.595
    500.015, 191387.137
    0.060, -11.598
    250.037, 89886.332
    0.092, -11.601
    125.065, 38883.652
    0.129, -11.604
    62.597, 12269.691
    0.188, -11.610
    31.393, 731.387
    0.676, -11.679
    16.034, -15.857
    23.713, -17.985
    27.553, -19.100
    29.473, 292.001
    27.671, -19.121
    28.572, 88.339
    27.831, -19.150
    28.201, 5.087
    28.124, -12.353
    28.178, -0.001
    28.179, 0.111
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\newcommand{\makeChart}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(##1<0,##1,ln((##1) + sqrt((##1)^2 + 1)))}\pgfmathresult},
    y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{##1}\pgfmathresult},
}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1000,
    ytick={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    yticklabels={-20,-10,0,10,100},
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] table[col sep=comma, x=x,y=y] {#1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\makeChart{something}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have marked the earlier answer as the accepted but this is basically the same!